# Single glob expression to match contents of subdirectory with given name but not contents of (parent) directory with such name

Tags: glob

Given the following paths:

```
@c8y/apps
@c8y/client
project-a/@c8y/client
project-b/@c8y/client
foo/@c8y/client
bar/@c8y/client
baz/@c8y/client
qux/@c8y/client
```

I expect to match only the entries that have "@c8y" as the subdir:

`☒ @c8y/apps
☒ @c8y/client
☑ project-a/@c8y/client
☑ project-b/@c8y/client
☑ foo/@c8y/client
☑ bar/@c8y/client
☑ baz/@c8y/client
☑ qux/@c8y/client`

I tried `**/@c8y/**` and `{!,**/}@c8y/**` but failed and pretty much stuck afterwards

Is there a single glob expression that can achieve this?

Comment: How about `project-?/@c8y/client`?

Comment: @melpomene Ah sorry, I oversimplified my case, the name of the project can actually consist of any random characters. I edited my quest. :)

Comment: How about `*/@c8y/client`?

Comment: @melpomene Oh my gosh, I'm a dork. That makes it work. Would you mind to put that as an answer? Btw, I also tried `**/@c8y/client` but do you know why it also matches `@c8y/apps` and `@c8y/client`? 

Comment: I'd need to see a [mcve] for that one.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require exactly one subdirectory before `@c8y`, you can just use `*`:

```
*/@c8y/client
```

Unlike `**`, which matches 0 or more path components, `*` always matches exactly one level.